# Js appendChild not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to append a title and hr element to the popup,
but when i append this, the popup does not append to the body anymore.
What am i doing wrong? However if i don not append the title and hr to the popup he shows up perfectly.

```
// selecteer alle elementen met de class "editHose"
var edits = document.getElementsByClassName('editHose');

// voeg eventlistener toe aan elke knop om het edit kadertje te laten verschijnen
for(i=0; i<edits.length; i++)
{

    // eventListener toevoegen aan elke knop
    edits[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

            // maak overlay aan
            var overlay = document.createElement('div');
            overlay.setAttribute('id', 'overlay');

                // append overlay to body
                document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(overlay);

            // maak de popup div aan
            var popup = document.createElement('div');
            popup.setAttribute('id', 'popup');
            popup.setAttribute('class', 'form-signin')

            // maak title en regenboogbalkje onder titel aan
            var title = document.createElement('h3');
            title.setAttribute('class', 'form-signin-heading');
            var line = document.createElement('hr');
            line.setAttribute('class', 'colorgraph');

                // append title en line to popup
                popup.appendChild('title');
                popup.appendChild('line');

                // append popup to body
                document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(popup);

    });

}
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: instead of `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]`, why don't you use `document.body`?

Comment: I am pretty new with Js so thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what the problem is:

```
            popup.appendChild('title');
            popup.appendChild('line');
```

should be

```
            popup.appendChild(title);
            popup.appendChild(line);
```